# Is zero a singular point of this function?

Tags: complex-analysis, indeterminate-forms

$$f(z)=\frac{z^3}{z+z^5}$$I thought that this function has 5 singular points. But my friend is convinced it only has four because if you write is as$$f(z)=\frac{z^2}{1+z^4}$$ then it is defined at f(0). This is really confusing me. Looking at the original function, it seems to me like 0 should be a (removable) singular point. I mean if you plug z=0 into it, it doesn't looke like f(z) is analytic to me...

Comment: hmmm, I think $z = 0$ is a removable discontinuity.  It certainly is if the domain is $\mathbb{R}$ but I'm not sure if the domain is $\mathbb{C}$.  Remember the limit has to exist, which means it has to be $\frac{z^2}{1 + z^4}$ from every possible direction.

Comment: but the numerator and the denominator are entire functions, so can't you use L'Hoptials rule for that limit?

Answer (score 1):

You are correct - the function is defined everywhere except at the 4 roots of -1, and at $z=0$. I think the term removable singularity that you used is correct - it is possible to define a function such that: 
$$f(z) = \begin{cases} \frac{z^3}{z+z^5} & z \neq 0, \\ \\ 0 & z = 0. \end{cases} $$

Comment: But if it's removable, then as far as Residue Calculus is concerned, it's not a singularity, right?

Comment: **Correction**: Four roots of $\color{red}{-}1$

Comment: @Sabyasachi Yes, thank you!!!

Comment: @Jared If it is a removable singularity, it is still a singularity - in this case though, the residue about the point is 0, if that answers your question.

Comment: @Jared: Be careful--removable singularities include those like $z=0$ for $f(z)=\dfrac{\sin z - z}{z^3}$.